# Most sensitive findbugs options in ant

Tags: java, ant, static-analysis, findbugs

I am running find bugs in ant and am trying to set everything (attributes, options, etc) in my ant build.xml to the most sensitive settings for finding bugs. From reading the documentation and looking at example here is what I concluded will be the most sensitive settings for if a bug is ran into. If it is not please let me know any attribute, options, etc that needed to be added or changed to find all the bugs that may be in my code.

```
<target name="findbugs" depends="jar">
    <findbugs home="/home/me/Desktop/findbugs"
        output="html"
        outputFile="bc.html"
        effort="max"
        reportLevel="low"
        workHard="true" 
        debug="true">
        <auxClasspath path="../foo/bin"/>
        <auxClasspath path="../bar/bin"/>
        <sourcePath path="../foo2/src" />
        <class location="bin/"/>
     </findbugs>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `workHard="true"` since you already have `effort='max'`. They're just synonyms of each other. Otherwise, it looks like you have it.

There are `includeFilter` and `excludeFilter`, but if you don't list either of those, you get all bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that before so will take that out and as of now I want to include all bugs so I dont need to use include or exclude yet.